# How do I FileUtils.cp_r a directory to another directory when there's a file with the same name?

Tags: ruby

Given a directory `A` and a file `B`, I would like to make a copy of `A` and all it's contents and name it as `B` in  the same directory.

If I try to do this with `FileUtils.cp_r('A/', 'B/')`, this fails with the error:

```
File exists - B (Errno::EEXIST)
```

How do  I specify that I want the destination directory to be a directory named `B`, and NOT the file `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most filesystems require that names be totally unique in a given directory: a name cannot refer to both a file *and* a directory, for example.

Therefore, you will not be able to create a directory called `B` if a file also called `B` already exists.

You'll have to unlink, rename, or otherwise move the file, or pick a different name for the directory.